# How to query Overpass area through leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

I have a `OpenstreetMap` with `leaflet`. I'm using [this](https://github.com/kartenkarsten/leaflet-layer-overpass) Plugin for leaflet to query with Overpass.

```
var opl = new L.OverPassLayer({
  query: "(area['name'='Roma']; node(area)['amenity'='drinking_water']);out;",


});
```

But my Map is showing nothing when used with the Plugin.

What is wrong?

Note: My query is working based on [this](http://overpass-turbo.eu/).

EDIT:

This query is working with Plugin but not on http://overpass-turbo.eu/ ?!

```
var opl = new L.OverPassLayer({
query: "(node(BBOX)['amenity'='drinking_water'];);out;",
```

});

FULL EXAMPLE:

```
var attr_osm = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
attr_overpass = 'POI via <a href="http://www.overpass-api.de/">Overpass API</a>';
var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {opacity: 0.7, attribution: [attr_osm, attr_overpass].join(', ')});

var map = new L.Map('map').addLayer(osm).setView(new L.LatLng(49.592041, 8.648164),2);

//OverPassAPI overlay
var opl = new L.OverPassLayer({
  query: "(node(BBOX)['amenity'='drinking_water'];);out;",


});

map.addLayer(opl);
```

Comment: Can you see any HTTP requests being made to Overpass in your browser console? What is the response?

Comment: Are you able to publish a full code sample @Khan that we could use to recreate your issue?  For example are you adding the opl to the map using  `map.addLayer(opl)` after creating the new layer?

Comment: please make question self contained, avoidmusing links called this and that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with another [plugin](https://github.com/GuillaumeAmat/leaflet-overpass-layer) .

I can use the overpass-turbo query:

```
var attr_osm = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
attr_overpass = 'POI via <a href="http://www.overpass-api.de/">Overpass API</a>';
var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {opacity: 0.7, attribution: [attr_osm, attr_overpass].join(', ')});

var map = new L.Map('map').addLayer(osm).setView(new L.LatLng(43.592041,2.648164),14);


var opl = new L.OverPassLayer({
query: "node[amenity=drinking_water]({{bbox}});out;",
});

map.addLayer(opl);
```

or with custom circle on Map

```
var opl = new L.OverPassLayer({
query: "node[amenity=drinking_water]({{bbox}});out;",
onSuccess: function(data) {


    for(i=0;i<data.elements.length;i++) {
      e = data.elements[i];
      
   
    
      var pos = new L.LatLng(e.lat, e.lon);
      var color = 'green';
      L.circle(pos, 5, {
        color: color,
        fillColor: '#fa3',
        fillOpacity: 1,
      }).addTo(map);
     
    }
  },
});

map.addLayer(opl);
```

You can even convert the data received from Overpass with [this](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson)
to **GeoJson.** It is possible to draw ways and area directly.

Answer (score 4):

Your zoom level is much too low, you're basically retrieving data for a large part of the earth. As a consequence your Overpass query times out and you won't get any result.

Change

`new L.LatLng(49.592041, 8.648164),2)`

to

`new L.LatLng(49.592041, 8.648164),14)`

In addition I recommended to:

- add a `[timeout:x]` parameter to limit the runtime of your query
- add a maximum number of object you want to query, e.g. `out 100;` for max. 100 nodes.

Also, you cannot use `(BBOX)` in overpass turbo. The correct syntax for overpass turbo would be `({{bbox}})`.